# Index parameter type for operator[] on pointers and arrays

Tags: c++

What is the natural parameter type for the operator [] on pointers, as in:

```
struct foo
{
  value_t operator[](<TYPE?> i)
    { return data[i]; }

  value_t * data;
};
```

I know that I can feed in any integer type, but what is the natural type for array indexing, ie. the one which does not cause implicit conversion?

Comment: `size_t` is a natural choice

Comment: Is that really what the compiler uses? size_t is unsigned, but I am certainly allowed to use negative indices in C++ indexing.

Comment: The compiler uses what, where? Define what you mean by natural. If your container doesn't support negative indexing, than it's natural to accept only an unsigned index.

Comment: By "natural" I mean "a compiler does not perform implicit conversion". If there is a standardized data type for that, what is it? And if it's not standardized (like some compilers accept negative indices, others not, or compilers use different data types internally), then I'm also grateful for authoritative information on that.

Comment: mmm... I don't think the standard specifies a specific integral data type. But if I had to venture a guess, I'd say it's a type which holds `sizeof(integral_type) == sizeof (pointer)`. So `long`, probably.

Comment: I don't have a standard reference handy but any integral expression will technically work, if you're careful about overflow issues and such.

Comment: However, that's limiting yourself to a platform and compiler implementation. Not to mention it's thinking in terms of the underlying machine rather then in terms of the abstraction you are implementing.

Comment: But you can't assume `sizeof(long) == sizeof(pointer)`, that's what `uintptr_t` is for, explicitly. `size_t` is for array indices, which might not have the same range either.

Comment: @StephenLin, OP is asking about a type which supports negetive values. But still, you should collect all the information you laid out in comments into an answer.

Answer (score 5):

`operator []` on pointers can be any integral expression

To be general, `ptrdiff_t` is technically what you want, if the intention is for `data` and `data + i` to be any two arbitrary pointers in either other and to arbitrary blocks of memory, since `ptrdiff_t` is defined as a signed type for holding the difference between two pointers (however, it's not guaranteed to not overflow: `ptrdiff_t` on machines with 32-bit pointers is typically 32-bit, not the next signed integral size higher)

In `std::vector<T>`, `size_t` is (typically) used, because `std::vector` has the additional restriction that the pointer points to the beginning of a block and indexing is only allowed within the allocated block, which cannot be larger than `size_t` by definition, and no negative indicies are allowed. `size_t` can be smaller than `ptrdiff_t` or `uintptr_t` (the unsigned integral type that can hold a pointer), for example on segmented architectures in which memory allocations are limited to one segment but pointers are not.

Now, if the intention is that `data` and `data + i` are part of the same block of memory but not necessarily such that `data + i >= data`, then I don't think there's an exact fit natural data type (i.e. a signed counterpart to `size_t`...I could be wrong) in Standard C++ (`ssize_t` is a POSIX extension), but you can go with `ptrdiff_t` since it's guaranteed to be at least as large as what you want.

There's no guarantee that `sizeof(long)` or `sizeof(int)` have any relationship with `sizeof(ptrdiff_t)` or `sizeof(size_t)`...assuming so can lead to nasty bugs.

**EDIT**: Technically, there's no portable way to obtain `data` and `i` such that `data` and `data + i` are both valid pointers and point to different objects in different allocation blocks, since the standard only guarantees that pointer arithmetic is well-defined within an allocated block, so if you're relying on doing so then your program is non-portable anyway. (Not that it won't work, in most cases...)